# Subsetting of data.frames with variable name vs. column number

Tags: r, subset

I am fairly new to R and I have run into a problem with subsetting data frames a number of times. I have found a fix but would just like to understand what I am missing.

Here is an exemplary bit of code, where I don't understand the functional difference.

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1:10), V2 = c(rep(1, times = 10)))
```

this produces an "undefined columns selected" error:

```
df1 <- df[df$V1 < 5, df$V2]
```

but this works:

```
df2 <- df[df$V1 < 5, 2]
```

I don't understand why when reffering to the column by its name via $V2 I do not recieve the same result as when reffering to the same column by its number.

This is a really basic question, I am aware, but I would just like to get my head around it.

Thanks and also sorry if formatting is off or anything (first time posting..),

Christoph

Comment: *Why* might be hard to answer... but examples of correct syntax would be`df[df$V1 < 5, "V2"]` or `df[df$V1 < 5, ]$V2`

Answer (score 0):

`df[df$V1 < 5, df$V2]` doesn't give an `"undefined columns selected"` error.

```
df[df$V1 < 5, df$V2]
#  V1 V1.1 V1.2 V1.3 V1.4 V1.5 V1.6 V1.7 V1.8 V1.9
#1  1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#2  2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
#3  3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
#4  4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4
```

As you have only 1 in `df$V2` and 1st column is present in your dataframe. It selects 1st column for `length(df$V2)` times and as it is not advised to have columns with same name it adds prefix `.1`, `.2` to it.

This is same as doing

```
df[df$V1 < 5, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

It would give an undefined column selected error , if you select columns which are not present in data.

```
df[df$V1 < 5, c(1, 3)]
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$V1 < 5, c(1, 3)) : 
>     undefined columns selected

There are different ways in which you can access data

By column name which is

```
df[df$V1 < 5, "V2"]
#[1] 1 1 1 1
```

Or

```
df$V2[df$V1 < 5]
```

and by column position.

```
df[df$V1 < 5, 2]
#[1] 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this! In my first example (before I posted) I had only 20s in the second column, which then produced the error. And through your explanations I think I understood, that when I subset columns by "$Variable", I do not select this column, but rather select all columns contained in the vector that is "df$Variable". Is this a correct way of putting it? This is why it only produces an error if the content of "V2" > than ncol(df), right?

Comment: @cmr.hauber absolutely correct. It doesn't understand `V2`  from `df$V2`, it takes values of `df$V2` and uses them as index to subset columns. If there is any value in `V2` which is greater than `ncol(df)` it produces an error.